# Java enhanced for loop picking the highest and lowest number

Tags: java

I'm working on this project, and I've been stuck for a while now.

I am what they say a "noob" in the wonderful world of Java programming..

I've managed to get the highest number working. It only prints 4 times now, but I can't get the lowest number to work.

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringConversion test = new StringConversion();
    // Make our input / output object
    int d1;
    int d2;
    int d3;
    int d4;
    int d5;

    ConsoleIO io = new ConsoleIO();


    io.writeOutput("Click below this message, type something and press ENTER");

    // Tell it to read something from the
    // console (the program waits for this to happen):
    String input1 = io.readInput();
    String input2 = io.readInput(); 
    String input3 = io.readInput();
    String input4 = io.readInput();
    String input5 = io.readInput();
    // etc. etc. Here you can see that the value was correctly
    // stored in our local 'input' variable.


    // string omzetten naar int
    String i1 = input1;
    String i2 = input2;
    String i3 = input3;
    String i4 = input4;
    String i5 = input5;

    d1 = Integer.parseInt(i1);
    d2 = Integer.parseInt(i2);
    d3 = Integer.parseInt(i3);
    d4 = Integer.parseInt(i4);
    d5 = Integer.parseInt(i5);
    int antwoord = d1+d2+d3+d4+d5;
    // totaal rekensom
    System.out.println("total: ");
    System.out.println(d1+d2+d3+d4+d5);

    // gemiddelde som
    int gemiddelde = antwoord / 5;
    System.out.println("avarage: ");
    System.out.println(gemiddelde);
    // hoogste getal
    int zeeslag[] = {d1, d2 , d3 , d4 , d5};
    int max;
    int min;
    // het op dit moment maximum 
    max = zeeslag[0];
    min = zeeslag[0];
    //array doorlopen
    for (int i: zeeslag) { 
        if (i > max){
            max = i;
        System.out.println("highest number: " + i);

        }
        else if(i<min){
        min = i;
        System.out.println("lowest number: " + i);
        }

    }

    // laagste getal
    input1 = io.readInput();
    input2 = io.readInput();
    input3 = io.readInput();
    input4 = io.readInput();
    input5 = io.readInput();

}

}
```

Comment: What does not work? What did you expect and what happened instead?

Comment: You've got a lot of useless variables there.

Comment: Try adding a sample input and output section.

Comment: Try to give some more information on this, tell us what you have tried to get this to work. It will give people a better idea what you are talking about as well as possible ways to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your code quite a bit shorter:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {

int[] zeeslag = new int[5];
int total = 0, min = Integer.MAX_VALUE, max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
// Make our input / output object
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

for(int i = 0; i <5; ++i)
{
    System.out.println("Enter number " + (i+1) + " of " + 5 + ":" );
    zeeslag[i] = sc.nextInt();
    total += zeeslag[i]; // total and average
    if(zeeslag[i] < min)
        min = zeeslag[i];
    if(zeeslag[i] > max)
        max = zeeslag[i];
}

System.out.println("total: " + total);
System.out.println("Average: " + (total/5));
System.out.println("Lowest: " + min);
System.out.println("Greatest: " + max);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to print the `max` and `min` and not `i`. Also, they should be after the `for` loop because you need to compare with all the elements in the array before printing the maximum and minimum value.

```
for (int i : zeeslag) {
    if (i > max) {
        max = i;
    } else if (i < min) {
        min = i;
    }
}
// print the max and min after the for
System.out.println("highest number: " + max); // print the max value and not i
System.out.println("lowest number: " + min); // print the min value and not i
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the whole array inside the loop and then print the result.

```
   max = zeeslag[0];
   min = zeeslag[0];

   for (int i: zeeslag) { 
       if (i > max){
             max = i;
       }
       else if(i<min){
             min = i;
       }
   }
   System.out.println("highest number: " + max);
   System.out.println("Lowest number: " + min);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help ^^ Allot of usefull help around here